# JSP Login issue in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have created a login session in JSP which is connected to a database.

I have 3 rows of in my admin table. The problem is that when I enter the correct credentials as they are in the table, it does nothing when I login. Its only when I enter the last row (username and password) of the admin table, that it logs me in successfully. But when I enter the previous usernames and passwords which are in the table, it does not log me in. Why is that so? 
My codes are below:

**LoginManager.java**

```
public class LoginManager {

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cms";
String user = "root";
String pass = "root";


    ArrayList<Login> lgs = new ArrayList<Login>();
    public ArrayList<Login> log(String userType, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        Statement stt = con.createStatement();
        if(userType.equals("Administrator")){
            String admin = "SELECT * FROM admin";
            ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery(admin);
            while(rs.next()){
                String logid = rs.getString("LoginName");
                String pw = rs.getString("Password");
                String fname = rs.getString("FirstName");
                String lname = rs.getString("LastName");
            Login lg = new Login();
            lg.setUsername(logid);
            lg.setPassword(pw);
            lg.setFname(fname);
            lg.setLname(lname);
            lg.setUserType("Administrator");
            lgs.add(lg);
            }
            con.close();
            rs.close();
            stt.close();
        }

        return lgs;
    }
```

**Login.java**

```
  package cms;

  import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    public class Login {
private String userType;
private String username;
private String password;
private String fname;
private String lname;

@Id
public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
}
public void setUserType(String userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setFname(String fname){
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getFname(){
    return fname;
}

public void setLname(String lname){
    this.lname = lname;
}

public String getLname(){
    return lname;
  }
   }
```

**Part of the JSP Code**

```
    <%@page import = "java.util.*, cms.*" %>
<jsp:useBean id = "lm" class = "cms.LoginManager" scope = "session"/>

      <%
    Boolean submitted = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("isSubmitted"));
  int success = 0;
      if(submitted){
  String type = request.getParameter("type");
  String user = request.getParameter("userInput");
  String password = request.getParameter("pw");
 ArrayList<Login> lgs = lm.log(type, user, password);

 Login lg = new Login();
for(int i=0; i <lgs.size(); i++)
 lg= lgs.get(i);


 if((user.equals(lg.getUsername()) && password.equals(lg.getPassword()) && type.equals("Administrator"))){
    session.setAttribute("name", lg.getFname() + " " + lg.getLname());
    session.setAttribute("type", lg.getUserType());
     response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
 }else{

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are having logical bug in your jsp code. first you are iterating through all users and then you are validating the user. make it something like this and it will work

```
   Login lg = new Login();
    for(int i=0; i <lgs.size(); i++){
     lg= lgs.get(i);
    if((user.equals(lg.getUsername()) && password.equals(lg.getPassword()) && type.equals("Administrator"))){
    session.setAttribute("name", lg.getFname() + " " + lg.getLname());
    session.setAttribute("type", lg.getUserType());
     response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
 }else{

 }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same thing as the above ?

Comment: missing curly braces thats why your for loop is executing through all user and then only last user is assigned to lg and then your if-else statement are getting executed

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
Struggling with this since last 4 hours !

Comment: I have pasted my code here: http://pastebin.com/EurspTTY

Its no more working.. Can you help please ?

Comment: what issue you are facing now?

Comment: Basically, I can log in as admin, doctor, cashier.. 

Now, when I enter the username & password, it no longer directs me.. 
Does it have an issue with the curly brackets ?

Comment: are you getting redirected to index.jsp

Comment: Now.. no :( 
Please help bro